# EWS managed api to check whether an event exists in user's account or not

Tags: soap, office365, exchangewebservices, office365-apps

I uses ews managed api to create calendar events in user's account. Now I want to check whether calendar event already exists in the user's account or not before creating it.

> Suppose user had 10 events and I backed up. Now user deleted 4 events
>   so I only want to create those 4 events. How can I user for existing
>   calendar events in user's exchange online account.

I used this FindItem class property to find missed events but here I had to specify startdate and enddate. (I am looking for i.e. isExistItem class type for finding only deleted events and updated events)

```
<soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start" />
          <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:CalendarView MaxEntriesReturned="5" StartDate="2013-08-21T17:30:24.127Z" EndDate="2013-09-20T17:30:24.127Z" />
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:FolderId Id="AAMk" ChangeKey="AgAA" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you always want to use a CalendarView when looking at appointments because that expands recurring appointments. You can't use filters with a CalenderView so while it might not be as efficient as you like just retrieving and syncing for time period is generally the best approach and use the GOID property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidglobalobjectid-canonical-property as the identifier.